# C++ decorator: Access public function of base class from outside

Tags: c++, class, decorator

I want to try the use of C++ decorators and I have some questions.

Using this example: https://gist.github.com/dlivingstone/3006324#file-decoratormain-cpp

```
class AbstractNPC {
public:
    virtual void render() = 0;
};

class NPC: public AbstractNPC {
public:
    NPC() { }
    render(){...}
};

class NPCDecorator: public AbstractNPC {
private:
    AbstractNPC * npc;
public:
    NPCDecorator(AbstractNPC *n) { npc = n; }
    void render() { npc->render(); } // delegate render to npc data member
};

class Elite: public NPCDecorator {
public:
    Elite(AbstractNPC *n): NPCDecorator(n) { }
    void render() {
        cout << "Elite "; // render special features
        NPCDecorator::render(); // delegate to base class
    }
};

int main(){
    AbstractNPC *goblin1= new Elite(new Shaman(new NPC("Goblin")));
    ...
}
```

Do I have to to make each function virtual in AbstractNPC and redirect it from NPCDecorator to call it from outside?

```
class NPC: public AbstractNPC {
public:
    NPC();
    void render() {...}
    void func1() {...}
    void func2() {...}
    void func3() {...}
    void func4() {...}
    void func5() {...}
};
int main(){
    AbstractNPC *goblin1= new Elite(new Shaman(new NPC("Goblin")));
    call func1(); ???
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Class `NPC` here should be a concrete class with real implementations of all virtual functions. It can be the minimum simple NPC, where the implementations are the basic logic which should be used if no decorators at all are applied. Notice it doesn't even have a pointer member to redirect to.

Class `NPCDecorator` should have functions redirecting all public interface virtual calls to its `npc` pointer member.

Specific decorators like `Elite` and `Shaman` only need to define the virtual functions where they change the behavior. If `Elite` has no effect on what `func2` does, it can skip declaring and defining `func2` entirely, since it will be visible from base class `NPCDecorator`.

I would definitely change all pointers to `std::unique_ptr` and all `new` expressions to `std::make_unique` here, to avoid writing manual cleanup code and the potential for plenty of bugs and headache.

Comment: hm, with such scheme, would't be a decorator being an RCTP -base of concrete class more prudent? I don't see how dynamic calls can benefit this scenario?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Possibly. I didn't write this, just tried to explain how the linked example is most likely meant to be used. The one catch with direct CRTP is that you can't use a constant interface type and would need nearly every function to be a template. But probably there would be some fairly nice way to combine CRTP with type erasure to improve this whole pattern and eliminate all the nested pointer redirections.